# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: PlotlyService_1._plotly.purge is not a function

Tags: angularjs, charts, angular8, plotly-python, plotly.js

On leaving the angular component which uses the Plotly library, gives this error.
Probably an error while destroying the component and Plotly trying to access the purge function

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: PlotlyService_1._plotly.purge is not a function
TypeError: PlotlyService_1._plotly.purge is not a function
    at Function.remove (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:191063:37)
    at PlotComponent.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:191206:23)
    at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:88385:18)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:88344:13)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:88326:29)
    at destroyView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:98754:5)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:98913:13)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:98821:13)
    at destroyView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:98753:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many ways for this issue but finally found the reason.

The plotly-plot was used in 2 modules. The import was done via **plotlyViaCDNModule**, which was causing the issue.

Use this instead:

```
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';
import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly.js';

PlotlyModule.plotlyjs = PlotlyJS;


imports: [ ....
        PlotlyModule,
]
```